# a routing module in the root component and the style files with the scss extension

Tags: angular

Consider a scenario where you’ve nodejs installed, npm and @angular/cli packages are installed globally. What is the command to create a new application which has the name `jersey-store` with a routing module in the root component and the style files with the scss extension?

Comment: https://angular.io/cli/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
ng  new jersey-store --routing --style=scss
```